# Javascript charCodeAt and fromCharCode not returning the same value

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have a Unicode character that works with a very specific font.

I need to take that character's code, add 8, and convert it back to a string.

Here's python code that works:

```py
char = ""
char == chr(ord(char)) # True
```

However, in Javascript, using the matching functions, it does not convert back correctly:

```js
const char = "";
char == String.fromCharCode("".charCodeAt(0)) // false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use characters from Unicode astral planes, this is what you need:

```js
const char = "";
console.log(char === String.fromCodePoint("".codePointAt(0)));
```

See also:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

[What every JavaScript developer should know about Unicode](https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/)

[JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)

[Unicode-aware regular expressions in ES2015](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex)

[ES6 Strings (and Unicode, ❤) in Depth](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-strings-and-unicode-in-depth)

[JavaScript for impatient programmers. Unicode – a brief introduction](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_unicode.html)

Comment: Side note: python strings are UTF-8, javascript strings are UTF-16, which is why this issue doesn't occur with python.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally frowned upon.  Links break over time.  Please expand this answer to explain the actual issue and fix in more detail.